# Is voltage selector on 5v or 3.3v?

Tags: voltage, usb, ground, voltage-divider, ttl

I bought this USB to TTL converter and it came with the option to switch between 5v and 3.3v. I want to use it at 3.3v, but I'm not sure where the (grounder?) should be placed? Thanks, see image below. (5v and 3v3 option is on the side upside down).

[image]

Comment: Data sheet is where? Have you read it? Any documentation links?

Comment: Plug it into your computer, and measure the votlage between VCC and GND with a multimeter.

Comment: No data sheet and the little manual it came with says you can switch between 5v and 3.3v, but dosen't specify how or give any useful info apart from downloading the driver. This is the amazon URL: https://www.amazon.ca/gp/product/B07BBPX8B8/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o00_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1

Comment: @DKNguyen, unfortunately I have no multimeter right now and it will take 3 days for me to get one.

Comment: In the future, never buy something without a datasheet.

Comment: @DKNguyen that jumper does not necessarily control the voltage on the Vcc pin.  Most likely it controls the logic voltage, though indeed without documentation, who knows?

Comment: @ChrisStratton Hmmm. I see your point. UART TTL idles high right? Then you can measure the TX voltage instead.

Comment: @DKNguyen no, TTL doesn't have a particular idle _output_ state.  But logic level UARTs actually do idle high...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the photo, the thing is set for 3.3 Volts.  To set it for 5 V, move the black jumper to cover the center and right pins.

Comment: Great, thanks aton!

Comment: While that's true, it's not clear what seeing it for 3v3 governs - eg, the logic voltage or the Vcc voltage.  Both?  Neither?